# Streamlit is not found when run my docker container from github actions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, streamlit

[Docker Image creation logs in github actions that indicates installation of streamlit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JBha.png)

6af83d23fe21d8a1a55ff68d32f9ed7b3c4da6d9bf032f26e8ccd3f56528e133
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "streamlit": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

```
Dockerfile
===================

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

EXPOSE 8501

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        software-properties-common \
        git && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]
```

Everything works perfectly when I build the Docker Image locally but fails during deployment

```
 requirements.txt 
===================
bentoml==1.0.25
joblib==1.2.0
pip-chill==1.0.1
torchvision==0.14.1
tqdm==4.64.1
wincertstore==0.2
boto3
mypy-boto3-s3
streamlit  


main.yaml file
===============


name: workflow
    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - main
        paths-ignore:
          - "README.md"

    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read

    jobs:
      integration:
        name: :Continues Integration
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout Code
            uses: actions/checkout@v3
            with:
              repository: Sparsha1303/Deep-Learning
              token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
              ref: main

          - name: Lint code
            run: echo "Linting repository"

          - name: Run unit tests
            run: echo "Running unit tests"
          



      push_to_registry:
        name: Push Docker image to Docker hub
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout out the repo
            uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
          - name: Setup Docker Build
            uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

          - name: Login to docker hub
            uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
            with:
              username: ${{secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME}}
              password: ${{secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD}}

          - name: Extract metadata (tags,labels) for docker
            id: meta
            uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
            with:
              images: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY }}/${{ secrets.IMAGE_NAME }}

          - name: Build and push Docker image
            uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
            with:
              context: "{{defaultContext}}"
              push: true
              tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
              labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}



      Continuous-Deployment:
        needs: push_to_registry
        runs-on: self-hosted
        steps:
          - name: Checkout
            uses: actions/checkout@v3
          
          - name: Configure AWS credentials
            uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
            with:
              aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
              aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
              aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}

          - name: Log in to Docker Hub
            uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
            with:
              username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
              password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

          - name: Pull images
            run: |
            
          - name: Run Docker Image to serve users
            run: |
             docker run -d -p 8501:8501 --name=stapp -e 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}' -e 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}' -e 'AWS_REGION=${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}'  ${{secrets.REGISTRY}}/${{ secrets.IMAGE_NAME }}:main
          - name: Clean previous images and containers
            run: |
             docker system prune -f
```

[Git Hub Actions Continuous Deployment Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kas06.png)

Not sure if I've configured the EC2 server incorrectly please help me debug this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue here relates to how you are installing Python packages. Are you sure that the `requirements.txt` in your repository includes `streamlit`?

Assuming that your project looks something like this:

```
├── app.py
├── Dockerfile
└── requirements.txt
```

And `requirements.txt` contains (your version may differ):

```
streamlit==1.32.2
```

You should not need to specify an absolute path to the `streamlit` executable because if it was installed successfully then it will already be on your path.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

EXPOSE 8501

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        software-properties-common \
        git && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]
```

I have tested this and it works both locally and on GitHub Actions. To be sure, you should look at the logs on GitHub Actions where you should be able to see the `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` step and witness that it is (or is not!) installing the `streamlit` package.

[image]